# Matlab Three Phase System Model

Tags: oscilloscope, matlab, phase, simulink

I have a question regarding MATLAB Simulink if anyone is familiar with the software.

I usually have no problems creating basic models like this one below:
I know the image is rather small.

It is basically 3 phase generator with internal series impedance > VI series measurement block > series ammeters > RL series transmission line impedance > RL series load with load volt meters.

[image]

But however, sometimes when I run my circuits and enter my oscilloscope, I don't see a pure sine wave. It appears rather choppy. I get the correct voltage and current values in my displays as I have calculated them also. I am nearly sure all my parameters like frequencies, base voltages etc are all typed in correctly.

This is what my scope looks like:

Any tips or ideas?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The time resolution of your scope view is too low.

Comment: @Janka, Thanks for your comment, you were correct. I don't know how to rate your comment on this forum.

Comment: If a fix-step solver is used reduce the timestep. If a variable step solver is used changed the refinement factor - see my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the final display not the actual data.

If you are using a fixed step solver then use a small timestep. If however you are using a variable timestep then you need to inform the solver to render/calculate additional datapoints.

Simulink is aware what hte actual signal is as it is an integration engine and is sensitive to zero-crossing. In rendering a plot it has deemed this is all the information that is needed to represent the data.

This does produce unexpected results.

Consider a 100Hz sinewave as below. Not very sinus

What is needed

[image]

What is needed is to change the default refinement factor *IF* you are using a continuous solver.

[image]

The defaults is 1 so change it to 100

[image]

You now have the expected waveform. What this does is requests the solver to generate additional points between the datapoints it needs to realise the waveform.

A good explanation is found at "guy on Simulink" blog. https://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2009/07/14/refining-the-output-of-a-simulation/

Comment: Ah yes, that solved my problem in continuous variable step solver, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**
I would assume this is because of your solver being set to auto. You can increase the resolution by defining a "Min step size" in the configurations for the solver. This will slow down simulation since your forcing simulink to run more steps than what it considers to be necessary

**A little bit more elaboration:**
Simulink will during simulation have a variable step-size for which it will adapt to the system you're simulating, I won't go into details (don't know them well enough to explain them). It will speed up your simulation by choosing a step size appropriate for your simulation. In your case I guess it considers your system to be simple enough to run with a somewhat big step size.

I wouldn't worry too much about this unless you need to generate figures.

**Also:** I wouldn't recommend to set a fixed-step solver unless you're working with a discrete system.

Comment: You're welcome! I would however follow @JonRB answer, it is much a better solution! I had no idea about the data refinement options!